# Image handlers - how to resize and make them larger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

How can I make the resize handlers for an image larger for a mobile application?

https://jsfiddle.net/xvraLpna/4/

```
<div class="demo" contenteditable="true">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed sodales purus, quis aliquet leo. Ut in purus lectus. Ut pulvinar, neque ut dignissim tristique, massa massa venenatis lorem, quis scelerisque diam sem a neque. Proin in suscipit tortor. Cras ac odio vel nisi dignissim vulputate. Cras nec nulla nisl. Nunc eget convallis orci. In neque arcu, rutrum molestie orci vel, mollis imperdiet erat. Morbi tincidunt est massa, et iaculis mi pharetra a. Phasellus libero justo, faucibus at diam porttitor, laoreet pellentesque justo. Morbi sed vestibulum ipsum, eget placerat felis. Cras lobortis rhoncus pharetra. Aliquam hendrerit molestie orci, sed mattis nibh. Duis mattis, nisl ac venenatis posuere, nisi ante imperdiet lacus, vitae congue nibh quam vitae nibh. Cras nibh quam, dictum nec libero at, porta ornare erat. 

    <img src="http://store.valvesoftware.com/images/sizing_chart_shirt.png" alt="" />

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-resizable-handle {
    background: #ababab;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
}

.ui-resizable-e {
    right: -5px;
    top: 50%;
}

etc...
```

JQuery:

```
$('img').resizable({
    handles: 'all'
});
```

If I comment out the jquery code above, then I get 8 small resize handlers, and all show up without being cut off. It works. But since this will be used in a mobile application, I'd like to make the handles larger.

If I uncomment the jquery code above, then I get larger grey squares (currently targeting for 9px height and weight, as styled in the .ui-resizable-handle class). I've tried adding extra div classes for each of the handler directions, but it looks messy and it would resize the larger content editable div instead of the image.

In the image below, the squares are too small to resize on mobile properly. However, clicking to show the resize handlers and resizing it works perfectly.
[image: Squares are too small]

In the image below, I've styled the handlers to make them larger (9px) and grey colored. I also added a couple lines of jquery in order to implement it. However, when I click on the image to resize it, I encounter two issues: 1) the smaller white boxes still show up along with the grey ones, and 2) the squares are now cut off at the edges, along with the missing black border.
[image: Larger grey squares don't quite work]

I'd like for the user to be able to add multiple images in the future.

What's the simplest way to go about resizing the handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Increase the `height` of the handlers with CSS.

For example:

```
.ui-resizable-s {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

If you want to create bigger handlers specific for certain devices ONLY like mobile devices, you can use media queries.

```
    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question to clarify a few points. I already have adjusted the handle size in the .ui-resizable-handle class but I encountered a few problems. The media queries will be very useful moving forward.

Comment: Sure, I updated it in the question as well: https://jsfiddle.net/xvraLpna/4/
I tried your suggestion but didn't see much difference. The bottom: 0; would fix the cut off edges, though I like how it looks when the handles aren't exactly aligned with the image. Curious if it's possible to keep it without the edges cutting off.

Comment: hmm I don't see the white handles, I just see the grey ones.

Comment: that's odd... so even when you click the image, the white handles don't appear? I can't get the grey ones to toggle on/off on mouse click, only the white ones. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using chrome, but I just checked in firefox and ie as well.